# How does css treat the space in class name?

Tags: html, css

If I have written class="container bg-red" and in css I write .bg-red{background: red;} then it makes the background red so does that mean css will treat container{background: red;} and .containerbg-red{background: red;} the same way?

I tried .container{background:red;} and i worked but .containerbg-red{background:red;} didn't work.

Comment: This is basic knowledge about css selectors.
```class="container bg-red"``` means the html-element has **2** classes, namely *container* and *bg-red*

Comment: spaces  will seperate Classes when you assign them in html. So: "container bg-red" will assign 2 classes to your html Element, the classes "container" and "bg-red".  If you then write as you did: ".containerbg-red{background:red;} you are basically trying to adress a third, completly different class that doesn't exist. The Class "contrainerbg-red".  If you want to only assign the Changes to an Element which has specifically the 2 classes of "container" and "bg-red" check out the Answer from Thuan Tran

Comment: CSS documentation is available for free that can teach you. For example: [MDN: Target an element if it has more than one class applied](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Type_Class_and_ID_Selectors#target_an_element_if_it_has_more_than_one_class_applied). Feel free to read through the documentation and learn from their examples.

Answer (score 2):

Both container and bg-red is in the same level so you have to write `.container.bg-red {}` it will select an element with both the classes container and bg-red

Answer (score 1):

`class="container bg-red"` means that you are applying both : `class="container"` and `class="bg-red"`.